# How decode windows 64bit hex value : little endian time?

Tags: c++, time, decode

[image: Convert result of Dcode.exe]

I want to decode windows 64bit hex value: little endian time in C++.

I have a value(=FB7E5D6A355DD201) but I don't know how decode this value in C++.

Please tell me a sample code or related site.

Comment: What is the target type? Double, unsigned long long int, long long int?

Comment: The target type is char[8]. Maybe I can change if you want. I take 8byte from file.

Comment: So you are saying you want to convert each pair of hex digits into corresponding char? In that case endianness doesn't matter. Anyway just use [stoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoi/) with base 16. If you want bigger sized integers then convert the final result via one of the [endian changing functions](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/endian.3.html) (posix).

Comment: @freakish umm.. actually no. I want to decode a value(=FB7E5D6A355DD201) to time (2016-12-24 Sat. 00:58:34).

Comment: @LeeSJ Dude, you should be more precise on what exactly you want to achieve. There's no time mentioning in your post. Then you talk about `char[8]`. And now time. Time as in what? As in `time_t` structure? Or `std::chrono::time_point`? Or what? How exactly is the initial buffer encoded? Parsing is not simply "I want this", you have to know the source and target formats. Also I assume that none of us knows what this DCode soft does.

Comment: @freakish Oh.. sorry, you misunderstand my question. As you can see the picture, I want to decode a value(=FB7E5D6A355DD201) to time. I don't know about time's format and maybe it is not matter if you can show a time like "2016-12-24 Sat. 00:58:34". I just want to convert a value(=FB7E5D6A355DD201) to time which is the picture shows(2016-12-24 Sat. 00:58:34).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In unix systems date/time is often (but not always) recorded as a 32-bit integer indicating seconds past since Epoch (00:00:00, Jan 1, 1970). But for *Windows 64-bit LE* format, it means "x100 nanoseconds past since `00:00:00.000,000,0 Jan 1, 1601`". Your hexadecimal number is a raw binary integer, so it can be easily interpreted by `scanf`.
Here's a piece of stuff that I found from one of my oldest C programs. You can optimize it and add time zone support by yourself.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int mDays[12]={31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
const int daySec = 86400;
int yearDays(int y){
    return 365 + (y%400==0 || (y%4==0 && y%100!=0));
    // Pre-Caesar calendar doesn't work well, don't add it
}
void win_u64tod(unsigned long long utime){
    int y=1601, d=0, mo=0, h=0, m=0, s=0, ms=0;
    ms = utime % 10000000;
    utime /= 10000000;

    while (utime >= daySec*yearDays(y)){
        utime -= daySec*yearDays(y);
        y ++;
    }
    if (yearDays(y) == 366) mDays[1]=29;
    d = utime / daySec;
    utime %= daySec;
    while (d >= mDays[mo]){
        d -= mDays[mo];
        mo ++;
    }
    h = utime/3600;
    utime %= 3600;
    m = utime/60;
    s = utime%60;
    printf("%4u-%2u-%2u %2u:%02u:%02u.%07u\n", y, 1+mo, 1+d, h, m, s, ms);
}

int main(){
    union{
        char c[8];
        unsigned long long ull;
    } a;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i ++){
        scanf("%2x", a.c + i);
    }
    win_u64tod(a.ull);
}
```

Sample input: `FB7E5D6A355DD201`
Sample output: `2016-12-23 15:58:34.6327803` (Please note time zone is not added)

Reference: [DATECONVERT](http://www.dmares.com/maresware/html/dateconv.htm)

Comment: Thanks you so much!!